# Graphical depiction of continuous convolution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, convolution

Continuous convolution is graphically introduced in many optics or signal analysis textbooks. I was trying to trace the earliest version of the graphical version of the following integral:

$$
x(t)=\int_{0}^{t} f(\tau) \cdot h(t-\tau) d \tau
$$

Currently, it is depicted as, and flip-shift method, where one of the function is reflected across the y-axis. Searching early articles, I found one from the 1950s, *Graphical Evaluation of a Convolution Integral*, in Mathematical Tables and Other Aids to Computation
Vol. 13, No. 67 (Jul., 1959), pp. 202-212 [paper on JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2002713?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

There the author does the reflection (or folding) but does not change the sign of the $\tau$ axis, instead, he suggests that:

1. Plotting $h(\tau),$ curve $H$ in Fig. $1 \mathrm{~A}$
2. Folding $f(\tau),$ i.e., plotting it with **$+\tau$** axis to the left, curve $F$ in Fig. $1 \mathrm{~B}$
3. Translating Fig. $1 \mathrm{~B}$ on Fig. $1 \mathrm{~A}$ such that the $\tau$ axes coincide; for evaluating $x(t)$ at $t=t_{1},$ slide Fig. $1 \mathrm{~B}$ on Fig. $1 \mathrm{~A}$ until the origin of the $\tau$ axis in Fig. $1 \mathrm{~B}$ falls on $\tau=t_{1}$ of the $\tau$ axis in Fig. $1 \mathrm{~A},$ see Fig. $1 \mathrm{C}$.

[image: Graphical convolution]

In modern books, when one of the functions is flipped the positive $\tau$ axis is kept to the right and the function is plotted against the negative $\tau$ values.

(i) My question is about **Step 2**, why didn't the author change the sign of $\tau$ values after folding $f(\tau)$.

(ii) Is there any earlier version of *graphical* interpretation of convolution integral, perhaps in non-English texts?

Thanks.

[image: Modern convolution]